# How to convert Swift Bool? -> String?

Tags: swift, casting

Given a `Bool?`, I'd like to be able to do this:

```
let a = BoolToString(optbool) ?? "<None>"
```

which would either give me `"true"`, `"false"`, or `"<None>"`.

Is there a built-in for `BoolToString`?

Comment: And you would want the true, false, and <None> to be strings?

Comment: @dannybess Sorry, missed that. Yes.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
let b1: Bool? = true
let b2: Bool? = false
let b3: Bool? = nil

print(b1?.description ?? "none") // "true"
print(b2?.description ?? "none") // "false"
print(b3?.description ?? "none") // "none"
```

or you can define 'one liner' which works with both Bool and Bool? as a function

```
func BoolToString(b: Bool?)->String { return b?.description ?? "<None>"}
```

Comment: Change `"none"` to `"<None>"`.  I think we have a winner here! :-)

Comment: That's not quite orthodox Swift programming, the conventions of conversion via type initializers is one of prominent feature of all data conversion APIs. However, `CustomStringConvertible`, which declares `description` is an API that semantically is supposed to be used not for data serialization but debugging purposes. You should always use String.init(_:) instead.

Comment: @IsaaсWeisberg is certainly right. The documentation for `description` discourages calling it directly. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible

Answer (score 76):

String(Bool) is the easiest way.

```
var myBool = true
var boolAsString = String(myBool)
```

Answer (score 26):

```
let trueString = String(true) //"true"
let trueBool = Bool("true")   //true
let falseBool = Bool("false") //false
let nilBool = Bool("foo")     //nil
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `?:` ternary operator:

```
let a = optBool == nil ? "<None>" : "\(optBool!)"
```

Or you could use `map`:

```
let a = optBool.map { "\($0)" } ?? "<None>"
```

Of the two, `optBool.map { "\($0)" }` does exactly what you want `BoolToString` to do; it returns a `String?` that is `Optional(true)`, `Optional(false)`, or `nil`.  Then the *nil coalescing operator* `??` unwraps that or replaces `nil` with `"<None>"`.

**Update:**

This can also be written as:

```
let a = optBool.map(String.init) ?? "<None>"
```

or:

```
let a = optBool.map { String($0) } ?? "<None>"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var boolValue: Bool? = nil
var stringValue = "\(boolValue)" // can be either "true", "false", or "nil"
```

Or a more verbose custom function:

```
func boolToString(value: Bool?) -> String {
    if let value = value {
        return "\(value)"
    }
    else { 
        return "<None>"
        // or you may return nil here. The return type would have to be String? in that case.
    }
```

}

Comment: So, no? There is no built-in way?

Comment: This defers to CustomStringConvertible i.e. the same solution as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with extensions!

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Bool {
  func toString(_ nilString: String = "nil") -> String {
    self.map { String($0) } ?? nilString
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
let b1: Bool? = true
let b2: Bool? = false
let b3: Bool? = nil

b1.toString() // "true"
b2.toString() // "false"

b3.toString() // "nil"
b3.toString("<None>") // "<None>"
```